# Get every possible combination of elements

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

How would you get every possible combination of 2 elements in an array?

For example:

```
[
    1, 
    2, 
    3, 
    4 
]

becomes

[
    [1, 2], 
    [1, 3], 
    [1, 4], 
    [2, 1], 
    [2, 3], 
    [2, 4],
    [3, 1],
    [3, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [4, 1],
    [4, 2],
    [4, 3] 
]
```

This answer uses brute force but is there a functional way with Ramda and or currying?  [Derive every possible combination of elements in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177026/derive-every-possible-combination-of-elements-in-array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an elegant solution:

```
//    permutations :: Number -> [a] -> [[a]]
const permutations = R.compose(R.sequence(R.of), R.flip(R.repeat));
```

Usage examples:

```
permutations(2, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
// => [[1, 1], [1, 2], ..., [4, 3], [4, 4]]

permutations(3, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
// => [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], ..., [4, 4, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
```

Comment: It is elegant, but it is returning something different from what was requested, as it repeats the elements.  This returns the n-element sequences drawn from a list.  And it's as elegant at that as I've seen.

Comment: You're right, Scott. This answer is wrong, but interesting nonetheless. :)

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing from Haskell:

```
as = [1, 2, 3]

f xs = do
  a <- xs
  b <- xs
  return $ if a == b then [] else [a, b]

main = print $ filter (not . null) . f $ as
```

This is [my Ramda version](http://goo.gl/ynKHKC):

```
var as = [1, 2, 3, 4]

var f = xs => 
  R.pipe(
      R.chain(a => R.map(b => a == b ? [] : [a, b])(xs))
    , R.filter(R.pipe(R.isEmpty, R.not))
  )(xs)

console.log(f(as))
```

PS. LiveScript has a nice syntax for this:
http://homam.github.io/try-livescript/#welcome/lists

For choosing a subset of ant size: [Ramda code](http://goo.gl/2NZp3F)

```
var g = (xs, n) =>
  n == 0 ? [[]] : 
    R.isEmpty(xs) ? [] : 
      R.concat(
          R.map(R.prepend(R.head(xs)), g(R.tail(xs), n - 1))
        , g(R.tail(xs), n)
      )

g(as, 3)
```

Comment: You can also skip the explicit filter by using `chain` instead of `map` (and dropping the `return` in the haskell example) e.g. `chain(a => chain(b => a == b ? [] : [[a, b]], xs), xs)`

Comment: This updated version answers perhaps a more interesting question than the OP asked, finding, say, all the 2-element combinations from a set of four distinct elements.  But the question distinguished between `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1]`, which this doesn't do.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want two elements, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35688824/1243641) from Oriol should do you fine.  But if you want something that extends to any size subgroup, something like this might do:

```
const permutations = (n, tokens, subperms = [[]]) =>
  n < 1 || n > tokens.length ?
    subperms        :
    R.addIndex(R.chain)((token, idx) => permutations(
      n - 1,
      R.remove(idx, 1, tokens), 
      R.compose(R.map, R.append)(token)(subperms)
    ), tokens);


permutations(2, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
//=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4], 
//    [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3]]

permutations(3, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
//=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2], [1, 4, 3],
//    [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3],
//    [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 4], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 4], [3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 2],
//    [4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 3], [4, 3, 1], [4, 3, 2]]
```

This version was slightly adapted from one [I presented](https://gitter.im/ramda/ramda?at=569a8b0fda358920486f13ff) in [Ramda's Gitter room](https://gitter.im/ramda/ramda).  There I suggested it was overwrought, but that was for full permutations.  It seems appropriate for n-combinations.

You can see it in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://goo.gl/d9lJkY)**.

Comment: @davidchambers: Thanks for the edit.  Working too quickly!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any library, you can do it trivially in vanilla-js using a nested loop:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    result = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i)
  for(var j=0; j<arr.length; ++j)
    if(i !== j)
      result.push([arr[i], arr[j]]);
```

Comment: But does this extend straightforwardly to any-sized subgroups?

Comment: @ScottSauyet No, but the question is about 2-conbinations, not n-combinations.

Comment: You're right.  I guess it was in a follow-up comment to another answer that the OP made it clear that the goal was probably more general.  Yours is clearly the best answer if the goal is simply 2-combinators.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any length of permutations just adjust it to cut off at 2.

```js
function permutate(input, output) {
  if (input.length === 0) {
    document.body.innerHTML += "<div>" + output + "</div>";
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    output.push(input[i]);
    permutate(input.slice(0, i).concat(input.slice(i + 1)), output);
    output.pop();
  }
}

permutate([1, 2, 3, 4], []);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "adjust it to cut off at 2?"

Comment: Adjust it to not continue past a depth of 2 recursions